# ¿Cómo extraer los dos primeros datos de cada sublista?

Tags: python

Quiero extraer los dos primeros datos de mis la lista pero me extrae las 2 primeras

```
a=[]

lista=[[2,8,7,1],[2,4,5,6],[5,7,8,10,11]]

def concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista):
    for i in lista:
        i=lista[0:2]
        a.append(i)


        return a


print(concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista))
```

Comment: Tu lista tiene otras listas como elementos. `lista[0:2]` te devuelve los dos primeros elementos de `lista`, que son a su vez listas ¿qué es lo que querías? ¿Los dos primeros elementos de la primera sublista? Entonces seria `lista[0][0:2]` ¿Los dos primeros elementos de cada sublista? entonces quita `i=lista[0:2]` y en cambio haz `a.append(i[0:2])`  (ya que `i` es cada sublista, dentro del bucle). No quieres que haya sublistas dentro `a`, sino elementos uno tras otro? Cambia `.append()` por `.extend()`

Comment: ¿Cual es el resultado esperado con los datos que publicas?

Answer (score 1):

Porque lista[0:2] devuelve una lista con los dos primeros elementos, puedes hacer algo como:

```
lista=[[2,8,7,1],[2,4,5,6],[5,7,8,10,11]]

def concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista):
    a = []
    for l in lista:
        for v in l[0:2]:
            a.append(v)

    return a

print(concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista))
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando comprensión de listas:

```
def concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista):
    return [y for x in lista for y in x[0:2]]
```

que es la forma compacta de

```
aux = []
for x in lista:
    for y in x[0:2]
        aux.append(y)
```

#### Demo

```
lista=[[2,8,7,1],[2,4,5,6],[5,7,8,10,11]]

def concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista):
    return [y for x in lista for y in x[0:2]]

print(concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista))
```

produce:

```
[2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 7]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

lista = [[2,8,7,1], [2,4,5,6], [5,7,8,10,11]]
a = list(chain(*tuple(zip(*lista))[0:2]))
print(a)
```

**zip(*iterables, strict=False)** devuelve un iterador de tuplas, donde la i-ésima tupla contiene el i-ésimo elemento de cada una de las secuencias hasta alcanzar la longitud de la menor de las tuplas, en este caso contendrá:

zip(*lista) -> ((***2***, *2*, *5*), (***8***, *4*, *7*), (**7**, 5, 8), (**1**, 6, 10)), donde las dos primeras tuplas contienen todos los elementos de la solución.

**chain(*iterables)** encadena secuencias consecutivas como si fuera una única secuencia, lo que permite devolver el resultado en una única lista.

Comment: que hace esto??

Comment: @christian he ampliado la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de usar `list.append()` es que estas agregando una lista dentro de otra lista, tendrías que agregar cada elemento por separado con otro *ciclo-for*.

Pero también puedes hacer un ***merge*** entre listas, en python puedes unir listas simplemente con el operador `+`, así: `lista_a + lista_b`.

Así que el código resultado sería:

```py
lista=[[2,8,7,1],[2,4,5,6],[5,7,8,10,11]]

def concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista):
    a=[]    # Recuerda inicializar cada vez que llamas la función
    for i in lista:
        # i=lista[0:2]  # Borrar esta
        # a.append(i)   # Borrar esta
        a=a+i[0:2]      # Agregar esta
    return a


print(concatenar_primeros_elementos(lista))
```

Output:

`[2, 8, 2, 4, 5, 7]`

Comment: También puedes hacer `a += i[:2]`